How do we add email classification or Sensitivity comparable to Outlook onto mail command on Linux
How do we add email classification onto mail command on Linux?
I'm currently using the following command:
mail -s "$(echo - e " Test\From:abc\nContent-Type: text/html")" -S -smtp="SMTP relay server" mailbox

edit: If I interpret the original poster's question correctly this would only be for outgoing mail and be similar to Microsoft Outlook which has a Sensitivity drop down with choices like unrestricted or third party proprietary TTPI where that syntax seems to just be appended to the mail subject line.  Is there a way to make this happen in Linux like it does in Microsoft Outlook?
google outlook email sensitivity and look at related pics to get an idea.
example: https://www.vumc.org/it/vumc-it-blog/use-sensitivity-labels-outlook-protect-email

"email classification" - do you mean a Content Type?

Do you want to "classify"(?) incoming or outgoing messages? Would adding an X-Wharever header to the mail suffice? Have you investigated procmail (for incoming mail)?

Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly do you mean with "add email classification onto mail command". How should the resulting mail look like? Or what do you expect to happen?

@Bodo - I attempted an edit of the post to clarify what I think was being asked.  At least it would be something I would be interested in knowing.

I never heard of the term "sensitivity" in the context of Emails. Sure this isn't some company-specific extension that someone wrote?
